# How do I truncate HmacSHA256 to 128 bits?

Tags: java, hmac, sha256, javax.crypto

Java supports three MAC algorithms:

- HmacMD5
- HmacSHA1
- HmacSHA256

I however need to sign someting using HMAC-SHA256-128, which is HmacSHA256 but truncated to 128 bits.

This example and variants of has circulated on stackoverflow:

```
String MAC = hmacHelper.calculatePlainMAC("00000000", "HmacSHA256");

String bgSecretKey="1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF";

public String calculatePlainMAC(String ascii, String algorithm)
{
  Mac mac = null;
  final Charset asciiCs = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
  try
  {
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(bgcSecretKey.getBytes(), algorithm);
    mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
    mac.init(signingKey);
    byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(asciiCs.encode(ascii).array());

    String result = "";
    for (final byte element : rawHmac)
    {
      result += Integer.toString((element & 0xff) + 0x100, 16);//.substring(1);
    }
    log.debug("Result: " + result);
    return result;
  }
  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
  catch (InvalidKeyException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
1051cd18118219e1261f41401891fd1911a91cf1bc1751db13e10617c1221131231c31ab15613f14412c1681d7132178
```

This is all good, except that I need a 128-bit result, which I know is

```
FF365893D899291C3BF505FB3175E880
```

I have no idea how they reached this result. What I do know is that the HMAC algorithm used is HmacSHA256-128. From what I understand this algorithm will generate a 256-bit result, question is, how do I truncate this into a 128-bits result, returning the known result above?

Comment: the result you have given is NOT 256 bits. It contains a bunch of extra '1' chars.  the commented substring(1) removes them. why is it commented out?

Comment: where do you get the value of bgcSecretKey from? there is no kind of truncation that converts the actual result into what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The following line always adds 3 characters to the string, starting with '1'. The commented substring(1) removes the 1. It is used so that single character results get a zero pre-pended.

```
result += Integer.toString((element & 0xff) + 0x100, 16);//.substring(1);
```

However, even when you fix this, the result does not contain the truncated result you are expecting.

```
05cd81829e26f44089fd91a9cfbc75db3e067c221323c3ab563f442c68d73278
```

This of course depends on the value of bgcSecretKey.

You need to use the same key/algorithm/truncation you used to derive the expected result.

Comment: I've refined the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "key" should be converted to it's binary representation, not to the binary representation of the string value!

Ie. bgcSecretKey.getBytes() should be javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(bgcSecretKey) or whatever function you prefer to convert hex to binary value.
Then it all works. The whole code:

```java
 @Test
    public void test_key() throws Exception
    {
        String SECRET = "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF";
        Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
        Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        SecretKeySpec secret_key = new javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(SECRET), "HmacSHA256");
        try
        {
            sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException e1)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Sha key couldn't be initialized", e1);
        }
        //Create KVV key, it's HMAC of eight zeros
        final byte[] kvv_bytes = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(CHARSET.encode("00000000").array());
        StringBuilder kvv = new StringBuilder(16);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(16, kvv_bytes.length); i++) //KVV, max 16 bytes
        {
            kvv.append(Integer.toString((kvv_bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        System.out.println(kvv.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
```